# Is there a way to intercept the mobile keyboard hide/open event?

Tags: c#, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

I want to hide the block when the keyboard opens and show the block when it hides.

Tried

```
<input type="text" @onfocusin="OnFocusInInput" @onfocusout="OnFocusOutInput"/>
@code {
    private bool isShowNav = true;
    
    void OnFocusInInput()
    {
        isShowNav = false;
    }

    void OnFocusOutInput()
    {
        isShowNav = true;
    }
}
```

But the phone has a navigation button "Back", which hides the keyboard but does not show my Nav

Comment: Really interesting question, does the `@onfocusin` works fine?

Comment: @DylanBarquilla, same as in browser

Comment: Can you provide a better explanation on   `But the phone has a navigation button "Back", which hides the keyboard but does not show my Nav` ?  What's the exact problem  ?

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT, I show a certain block when the user clicked on the input field and hide it when the focus disappears from the input field. When a user clicks on the input field, a keyboard appears and in order to hide it, he presses the "Back" button on the smartphone, I want to intercept the keyboard hiding event

Comment: Does `OnFocusOutInput` trigger when keyboard  hiding ? And Which platform/simulator did you test on ?

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT, Not really, OnFocusOutInput is triggered when I click not in the input area. No, i didnt, test only on android 9 api 28

Comment: Maybe you can try to intercept the back button event .

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT, yeah, i hope. is there any documentation on this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71172188/8187800.