# Disable back button functionality in MAUI Blazor

Tags: android, maui, .net-maui, maui-blazor

A have an app, created with MAUI + Blazor Hybrid and running on Android. The app has two pages: page1 and page2. When user navigates from page1 to page2 he can go back to page1 using Android software/hardware back button. What I want is to prevent user from doing that until app logic allows to do so.

In native Android it is possible to override `onBackPressed()` and achieve that. But in Blazor I can't find a way to deal with it. I need to simply block Back event, without page reload, blinks and other possible side effects, like button was not pressed at all. There are a few JS hacks, but they leads to current page reload and this is not appropriate for me.

So is there any way to achieve that kind of native behavior in MAUI + Blazor on Android?

Comment: How do they navigate from page 1 to page 2? That is a link or button within the Blazor content? An alternative approach (if appropriate) is to instead have a Maui toolbar or menu bar, above (or to the side of) a Blazor WebView. Then navigation would be Maui code - and you have control over what back button does.

Comment: It would not help with android back button. Event is passed into BlazorWebView and I can't find a way to prevent it.

Comment: Ok. Sounds like the BlazorWebView has registered itself with the back button. Sorry, I don't know how to prevent that.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that there is no way to do it in the Maui/Blazor classes (at least I couldn't find one), the `MainPage.OnBackButtonPressed()` is not called, when there is a back navigation possible, instead it automatically navigates backards.

What's possible though is to intercept it already in the `MainActivity.cs`:

```
public override bool DispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)
{
    // Workaround: The back button will automatically navigate back if possible, it is not
    // possible to intercept it in MainPage.OnBackButtonPressed().
    if ((e.KeyCode == Keycode.Back) && (e.Action == KeyEventActions.Down))
    {
        bool handled = TryCloseCurrentlyOpenMenusOrDialogs();
        if (handled)
            return true;
    }
    return base.DispatchKeyEvent(e);
}
```